# How can I create a function and parent.function in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

The form will automatically send when page load, it will send to the iframe. But I want get the iframe content in the main page, so I create a function to test, parent.function. But I don't know where I should put this function and the parent.function. Firebug TypeErroe: parent.incomingValue is not a function. Help, appreciate.

```js
  $('#frame_form').submit();

  parent.incomingValue("Hello world");

function incomingValue(val) {
   alert(val)
}
```

```html
<form target="iframe">
  <input type="hidden" value="send"/>
  </form>

<iframe name="iframe"> </iframe>
```

Comment: Then why use an iframe at all, just submit the form ?

Comment: Could also send by ajax and skip the iframe. Do whatever you need to using the ajax response

Answer (score 0):

You should declare 'parent' as an object and set 'incomingValue' as a property like this:

```
var parent = {};
parent.incomingValue = function(val) {...}
```

Comment: I think OP is trying to use `window.parent` from inside iframe. i could be wrong though